# Embed both images and text inside email body

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Am a new bie with python, i want to build something to send emails with python smtp, i want to
also embed images from a glob path, while i also pass in parameters inside html

so far this is what have managed to do. send the email. but the images are not embeding inside the mail body but they are been sent as separte attachment files how do i embed all in one body

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
msg['Subject'] = "My text dated"
msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = MY_ADDRESS

email = "someome@gmail.com"
name = "someome"
```

**Here is the html tag where am trying to pass thress parameters for formating**

```
image_cid = make_msgid()

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <img src="cid:{image_cid}" alt="Logo" style="width:250px;height:50px;"><br>
       <p><h4 style="font-size:15px;">email.{email}</h4></p>
      <p><h4 style="font-size:15px;">Name.{name}</h4></p>            
    </body>
</html>
""".format(image_cid = image_cid[1:-1] ,email =email,name = name )
# Record the MIME types of text/html.

from glob import glob 
list_of_images = glob('*.jpg')
```

****Here am looping through all images  of formate jpg in current dir****

```
for filename in list_of_images:
fp = open(filename, 'rb')
msg_img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg_img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(filename))
msg_img.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename=filename)
msg.attach(msg_img)


part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
msg.attach(part2)


# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP(host='rtrt.rty.com', port=567)
s.starttls()
s.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
s.send_message(msg)
del msg
        
    # Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to embed both text and image in one now i want to embed multiple images but only getting one r the last image

```
msg['Subject'] = "My text dated"
msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = MY_ADDRESS


# set the plain text body
msg.set_content('This is a plain text body.')

# now create a Content-ID for the image
image_cid = make_msgid()
# if `domain` argument isn't provided, it will 
# use your computer's name
email = "someome@gmail.com"
name = "someome"
# set an alternative html body
msg.add_alternative("""\
<html>
    <body>
        <p>This is an HTML body.<br>
           It also has an image.
         <p><h4 style="font-size:15px;">email{email}</h4></p>
         <p><h4 style="font-size:15px;">Name{name}</h4></p> 
        </p>
        <img src="cid:{image_cid}"> 
    </body>
</html>
""".format(email="someome@gmail.com",name=name,image_cid=image_cid[1:-1]), subtype='html')
# image_cid looks like <long.random.number@xyz.com>
# to use it as the img src, we don't need `<` or `>`
# so we use [1:-1] to strip them off

    
    
from glob import glob 
list_of_images = glob('*.jpg')
        
for filename in list_of_images: 
# now open the image and attach it to the email
 with open(filename, 'rb') as img:
    # know the Content-Type of the image
    maintype, subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(img.name)[0].split('/')
    # attach it
    msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), 
                                         maintype=maintype, 
                                         subtype=subtype, 
                                         cid=image_cid)
```